# How to enable a popup control in wpf when I click inside a textbox?

Tags: wpf

This is something I want to add as a feature. I've already made e a class that saves the last user search text into a .txt file. I also have it to when the user opens my application the list of searches get loaded into a list. However, what I need help with is displaying this list my xaml.

What I want to achieve for the user is when he/she clicks inside the search box, I want to load the list last saved searches. I wanted it to show up in a ListView inside a Popup control just below the search box. This is how I have my xaml set up

```
<TextBox Grid.Column="1"
                 Width="100"
                 Name="TextBox"
                 Text="{Binding SearchText, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
            <TextBox.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type Popup}">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="IsOpen" Value="True" />
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="False">
                            <Setter Property="IsOpen" Value="False" />
                        </Trigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </TextBox.Resources>
        </TextBox>
        <Popup Name="SavedSearchesList">
            <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding SavedSearchesList, Mode=OneWay}"
                      SelectedItem="{Binding SavedSearchSelected, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">                
            </ListView>
        </Popup>
```

However when I click inside the Text Box my popup control is not opening. What am I doing wrong? Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the Trigger from the TextBox and try the following for your Popup:

```
<Popup Name="SavedSearchesList" IsOpen="{Binding IsFocused, ElementName=NameofTextBox}">
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding SavedSearchesList, Mode=OneWay}"
              SelectedItem="{Binding SavedSearchSelected, Mode=TwoWay, 
              UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">                
    </ListView>
</Popup>
```

Keep in mind that you have to set a name for your TextBox and replace 'NameofTextBox' with that name.
Hope this works.